# Setting "local" stage env variable in Serverless v1.x

Tags: serverless-framework

In the Serverless 1.x framework, you set environment variables in the `serverless.yml` file at the service root. I'm trying to set the `STAGE` variable that corresponds with the stage that the service is running in. It's easy for `dev` and `prod`, like so:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  ...
  stage: dev
  environment:
    STAGE: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
```

This means that if `--stage` is explicitly defined, then the env variable uses that. If it's not, it uses the default `dev`.

When I use `sls invoke local` however, the default stage will be `dev` and that's not correct. What's the best way to get the stage to be `local` when invoking locally?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is adding `-s local` to the command. This was starting to get too verbose for my liking, however, and it also increases the probability of accidentally deploying to a new stage called `local` which is obviously undesirable.

So, I created this helper bash function:

```sh
# Invoke serverless service
invoke() { 
    if [ "${1}" == "local" ]; then
        stage="local -s local"
    else
        stage="-s ${1}"
    fi

    payloads_dir="tests/payloads/"
    if [ -z $3 ]; then
        payload="${payloads_dir}${2}/default.json"
    else
        payload="${payloads_dir}${2}/${3}.json"
    fi

    if [ ! -f "${payload}" ]; then
        echo $payload
        echo "Payload does not exist."
        return 1
    fi

    time --format='%e seconds' serverless invoke $stage -f $2 -p $payload
}
```

Usage: `$ invoke stage function_name [payload_name]`

Examples:

```
$ invoke local myFunction
```

will invoke the function locally with the payload at `tests/payloads/myFunction/default.json` while applying the `local` stage env.

```
$ invoke dev myFunction my_payload
```

will invoke the deployed function with stage `dev` and payload `tests/payloads/myFunction/my_payload.json` (the stage env will be correct if the deployed service has the appropriate `serverless.yml` file).

This is clearly an opniniated implementation, but feel free to modify it to your liking!